# Show that a sequence of functions is not compact in $(C^1([-1,1]),\lVert\,\cdot\,\rVert_{\infty})$

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, uniform-convergence

Let $F:=(f_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ where $$\forall x\in[-1,1]\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,f_n(x):=\mid x\mid^{1+\frac{1}{n}}$$
I have to prove that $F$ is not **compact** in $(C^1([-1,1]),\lVert\,\cdot\,\rVert_{\infty})$.

My idea is to prove that $F$ is not *sequentially compact* w.r.t. the topology induced by the infinity norm.

In particular, if I prove that $f_n\to f$ *uniformly* on $[-1,1]$, where $f(x):=\lvert x\rvert$, we are done. Infact, every subsequence will also converge in norm to $f\notin C^1([-1,1])$.

Is this reasoning correct? 
If yes, how can I prove $f_n\to f$ uniformly on $[-1,1]$?

Comment: Sounds like it; you're basically showing that $F$ is not closed, and compactness implies closedness.  Note that in a metric space, sequential compactness is the same as compactness.

Comment: $F$ is closed, but not complete.

Comment: So my reasoning is totally wrong. How can I proceed?

Comment: No, your reasoning is correct. The sequence converges in the larger space $C^0([-1,1])$, and the limit does not lie in the subspace $C^1([-1,1])$. Therefore, the sequence has no subsequences that converge in $C^1$, whence $F$ is not compact. Well, you need to prove the uniform convergence to have a complete proof.

Comment: The answer by Hayden has made me confused. In this way I prove also that $F$ is not closed because it doesn't contain all its accumulation points?

Comment: $F$ is closed in $C^1([-1,1])$, but not in $C^0([-1,1])$. It has no accumulation points in the smaller space, but it has one in the larger. If $F$ were compact, it would be closed in _every_ larger space as long as that is Hausdorff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's enough to consider $x\geq 0$. Then
$$
\left|x\right|-\left|x\right|^{1+\frac{1}{n}}=
x-x^{1+\frac{1}{n}}=
x\left(1-x^\frac{1}{n}\right)=
$$
$$
=n^n\left(\frac{x^{\frac{1}{n}}}{n}\right)^n\left(1-x^\frac{1}{n}\right)
$$
By AM-GM inequality,
$$
\ldots\leq n^n\left(\frac{n\,\frac{x^{1/n}}{n} + 1 - x^{1/n}}{n+1}\right)^{n+1}=
\frac{n^n}{(n+1)^{n+1}}=\frac{1}{n+1}\left(\frac{n}{n+1}\right)^n\leq \frac{1}{n+1}\to0
$$